# Meteor access mongodb by name server side

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am fairly new to Meteor and trying to code my first bigger Meteor application. I am using the [Meteor synced cron package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) to access an API in specific time intervals. Everything is working fine. But I want to access the **cronHistory** collection which is maintained by the **Synced cron package* The name of the collection is 'cronHistory'. Is there a way to get a reference to this database on the server side ?

Something like:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
//Not working because collection already exists. I only want to get the collection by name, not creating a new one.
export default CronHistory = new Meteor.Collection('cronHistory');
```

I already found a lot of suggestions and implementations, but all of them were intended to access the mongodb from the client side.

Anyone have some suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to access collections by name on the server. You can, however, access the SyncedCron collection simply by `SyncedCron._collection`.

Comment: Thank you so far, for your help. I tried your code and it works. But when I try to to access all docs in the database by SyncedCron._collection.find(); it does not give me all docs. It just gives me some information about the whole DB. Besides this, when I try, SyncedCron._collection.findOne(); it gives me a valid doc as a result. You may know a function to get all docs? Or do I have an error while accessing all docs ?

Comment: It returns something like this: Cursor {
_mongo:
MongoConnection {
_observeMultiplexers: 'and so on'

Comment: @grahan How about `SyncedCron._collection.find().fetch()`?

Comment: Sometimes I ask myself, why I didn't find the solution by myself... Thank you very much, this solved it.